# Are there any Islamic mystics in the Guru Granth Sahib?

Tags: history, sufism

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mysticism#Islamic_mysticism):

> Guru Arjan, the fifth Sikh Guru, added religious mystics belonging to other religions into the holy scriptures that would eventually become the Guru Granth Sahib.

Were any Islamic mystics included within them?

Comment: I don't think it's directly related to Islam. And might be off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking people to relate or compare with Islam by searching for anything Islamic in other things is not constructive and off-topic. Instead present some example clearly and then ask to compare.

Comment: @servantWiser: I would put up an example if I had one - I'm asking if there are any; I agree that it isn't directly about Islam...however this is the closest one there is one the SE list.

Comment: Well, we don't know if there is anything Islamic, in Guru Granth Sahib, we've not read it till now, & I suggest, if you're too curious, search the [internet](https://www.google.co.in/search?sclient=psy-ab&site=&source=hp&q=hadith+adam+jesus+go+to+muhammad+intercession&oq=hadith+adam+jesus+go+to+muhammad+intercession&gs_l=hp.3...2259900.2278464.0.2279782.54.45.4.1.2.5.1415.16995.1j3j23j2j1j1j4j5.40.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..29.25.7142.AGSXRZ0WpeY&pbx=1&biw=1366&bih=667&dpr=1&cad=cbv&sei=xZssVZWDIY6CuwSh54D4BQ#q=comparison+of+islam+and+guru+granth+sahib) first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 6 writers with Muslim background, whose hymns are incorporated in Guru Granth Sahib, whom Sikhs call Bhagats(Devotee):

1) Devotee Kabir

2) Devotee Sheikh Fareed

3) Devotee Sadhana Qasai

4) Devotee Satta Dum

5) Devotee Balwand Rai

6) Devotee Bhikhan

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writers_of_Guru_Granth_Sahib